# How can I see detached docker containers?

Tags: docker, containers, detach

I started using docker only recently. It is my understanding that in order to mount the local folder into a docker volume inside the container `C1` on the image `image_name` can be done by running the following code:

```
var=$(pwd)
docker run -d --name=C1 -v $var:/host image_name
```

However, because I am detaching the container, I am not able to see it among the containers created doing `docker ps` or `docker container ls`.

However, if I run `docker volume list` and then `docker volume rm VOLUMEID` I get the error `volume is in use - [CONTAINER_C1_ID]`.

Any idea how can I see where C1 is?

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like your container is quickly exiting; `docker ps -a` shows stopped containers too.  Try running your container without the `-d` option and debug why it’s not starting up.

Comment: Your command seems to list the container if it was actually running ( even in detached mode). Most likely, your containers did not startup properly and reference to volume is still there somehow. you can see your container using `docker ps -a`  like @David Maze said, and then you can see logs using `docker logs <container_name>` to debug further.

Comment: your container is exiting fast , but still it keeps holding the volume , anyway u can use docker ps -a to list all the container including the ones in exit state

Answer (score 2):

I run container with:

```
docker container run -d ubuntu top
```

I can't see image with PS:

```
     $ ps

PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh -c cat /etc/hosts >/etc/hosts.bak &&     sed 's/^::1.*//' /etc/hosts.bak > /etc/hosts &&
   19 root      0:18 dockerd
   20 root      0:00 script -q -c /bin/bash -l /dev/null
   21 root      0:00 /bin/bash -l
   41 root      0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -o PermitRootLogin=yes -o PrintMotd=no [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
   75 root      0:15 containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml --log-level debug
  420 root      0:00 sshd: root@pts/2
  436 root      0:00 -bash
11806 root      0:00 /usr/local/bin/containerd-abhi-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id 385a36d3a51c997d98fa448d745777f1be8115e
11826 root      0:00 top
13525 root      0:00 ps
```

For list detached container, enter a command:

```
$ docker container ls

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
385e36d3a81c   ubuntu    "top"     9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes             bril_wu
```

Now for access container use command:

```
docker container exec -it 385e36d3a81c bash
```